# Increase speed of composition from list and map

Tags: java, optimization, arraylist, hashmap

I use a `Dico` class to store weight of term and id of document where it appears

```
public class Dico 
{
   private String m_term; // term
   private double m_weight; // weight of term
   private int m_Id_doc; // id of doc that contain term

   public Dico(int Id_Doc,String Term,double tf_ief ) 
   {
      this.m_Id_doc = Id_Doc;
      this.m_term = Term;
      this.m_weight = tf_ief;
   }
   public String getTerm()
   {
      return this.m_term;
   }

   public double getWeight()
   {
     return this.m_weight;
   }

   public void setWeight(double weight)
   {
     this.m_weight= weight;
   }

   public int getDocId()
   {
     return this.m_Id_doc;
   }                
}
```

And I use this method to calculate final weight from a `Map<String,Double>` and `List<Dico>`:

```
 public List<Dico> merge_list_map(List<Dico> list,Map<String,Double> map)
 {
    // in map each term is unique but in list i have redundancy

   List<Dico> list_term_weight = new ArrayList <>();

   for (Map.Entry<String,Double> entrySet : map.entrySet())
   {
       String key = entrySet.getKey();
       Double value = entrySet.getValue();

       for(Dico dic : list)
       {    
          String term =dic.getTerm();
          double weight = dic.getWeight();

          if(key.equals(term))
          {
             double new_weight =weight*value;                
             list_term_weight.add(new Dico(dic.getDocId(), term, new_weight));
          }                  
       } 
    }
    return list_term_weight;
 }
```

I have 36736 elements in the map and 1053914 in list, currently this program take lot of time to compile: `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` (total time: 17 minutes 15 seconds).

How can I get only the term from the list that equals the term from map ?

Comment: Use two maps instead of a map and a list.

Comment: How do you initialise the Map? do you have all the terms you will find in the list, or is it a subset?

Comment: You are talking about _compile_ time and _BUILD SUCCESSFUL_, even though your problem is obviously a **running time** one. Can you confirm?

Comment: yes because the next step is to use this term for classification of node with SOM neuronal net

Answer (score 4):

You can use the lookup functionality of the Map, i.e. Map.get() given that your map maps terms to weights. This should have significant performance improvements. The only difference is the output list is in the order as the input list, rather than the order the keys occur in the weighting Map.

```
public List<Dico> merge_list_map(List<Dico> list, Map<String, Double> map)
{
    // in map each term is unique but in list i have redundancy
    List<Dico> list_term_weight = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Dico dic : list)
    {
        String term = dic.getTerm();
        double weight = dic.getWeight();

        Double value = map.get(term);  // <== fetch weight from Map
        if (value != null)
        {
            double new_weight = weight * value;

            list_term_weight.add(new Dico(dic.getDocId(), term, new_weight));

        }
    }
    return list_term_weight;
}
```

### Basic test

```
List<Dico> list = Arrays.asList(new Dico(1, "foo", 1), new Dico(2, "bar", 2), new Dico(3, "baz", 3));
Map<String, Double> weights = new HashMap<String, Double>();
weights.put("foo", 2d);
weights.put("bar", 3d);
System.out.println(merge_list_map(list, weights));
```

Output

```
[Dico [m_term=foo, m_weight=2.0, m_Id_doc=1], Dico [m_term=bar, m_weight=6.0, m_Id_doc=2]]
```

### Timing test - 10,000 elements

```
List<Dico> list = new ArrayList<Dico>();
Map<String, Double> weights = new HashMap<String, Double>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1e4; i++) {
    list.add(new Dico(i, "foo-" + i, i));
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        weights.put("foo-" + i, (double) i);  // <== every 3rd has a weight
    }
}

long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<Dico> result1 = merge_list_map_original(list, weights);
long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<Dico> result2 = merge_list_map_fast(list, weights);
long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

System.out.println(String.format("Original: %d ms", t1 - t0));
System.out.println(String.format("Fast:     %d ms", t2 - t1));

// prove results equivalent, just different order
// requires Dico class to have hashCode/equals() - used eclipse default generator
System.out.println(new HashSet<Dico>(result1).equals(new HashSet<Dico>(result2)));
```

Output

```
Original: 1005 ms
Fast:     16 ms  <=== loads quicker
true
```

Comment: thank  your help but i have to comapre on term of map with all  terms and update weight when map.term = dic.term .

Comment: I'm slightly confused on expected inputs and outputs, could you update question with small worked example vales, I believe what I've done is equivalent as my tests show.

Comment: ok i am so confused for what i said your solution is very useful, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Also, check the initialization of the Map. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) The rehash of the map is costly in performance.

> As a general rule, the default load factor (.75) offers a good
>   tradeoff between time and space costs. Higher values decrease the
>   space overhead but increase the lookup cost (reflected in most of the
>   operations of the HashMap class, including get and put). The expected
>   number of entries in the map and its load factor should be taken into
>   account when setting its initial capacity, so as to minimize the
>   number of rehash operations. If the initial capacity is greater than
>   the maximum number of entries divided by the load factor, no rehash
>   operations will ever occur.
>
> If many mappings are to be stored in a HashMap instance, creating it
>   with a sufficiently large capacity will allow the mappings to be
>   stored more efficiently than letting it perform automatic rehashing as
>   needed to grow the table.

If you know, or have an approximation of the number of elements that you put in the map, you can create your Map like this:

```
Map<String, Double> foo = new HashMap<String, Double>(maxSize * 2);
```

In my experience, you can increase your performance by a factor of 2 or more.

Comment: maxSize * 2 might be a little overkill as far as size, but will reduce collisions and give better performance. With default load factor if you know the exact maximum size, the minimum size needed is maxSize * 4 / 3 + 1.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the `merge_list_map` function to be efficient, you need to actually use the `Map` for what it is: an efficient data structure for key lookup. 
As you are doing, looping on the `Map` entries and looking for a match in the `List`, the algorithm is O(N*M) where M is the size of the map and N the size of the list. That is certainly the worst you can get.

If you loop first through the `List` and then, for each `Term`, do a lookup in the the `Map` with `Map$get(String key)`, you will get a time complexity of O(N) since the map lookup can be considered as O(1).

In term of design, and if you can use Java8, your problem can be translated in terms of `Stream`s:

```
public static List<Dico> merge_list_map(List<Dico> dico, Map<String, Double> weights) {
    List<Dico> wDico = dico.stream()
            .filter  (d -> weights.containsKey(d.getTerm()))
            .map     (d -> new Dico(d.getTerm(), d.getWeight()*weights.get(d.getTerm())))
            .collect (Collectors.toList());
    return wDico;
}
```

The new weighted list is built following a logical process:

1. `stream()`: take the list as a *stream* of `Dico` elements
2. `filter()`: keep only the `Dico` elements whose `term` is in the `weights` map
3. `map()`: for each filtered element, create a `new Dico()` instance with the computed weight.
4. `collect()`: collect all the new instances in a new list
5. return the new list that contains the filtered `Dico` with the new weight.

---

**Performance wise**, I tested it against some text, [the narrative of Arthur Gordon Pym](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2149/2149-h/2149-h.htm) from E.A.Poe:

```
String text = null;
try (InputStream url = new URL("http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2149/2149-h/2149-h.htm").openStream())  {
    text = new Scanner(url, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();    
}
String[] words = text.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+");
System.out.println(words.length); // => 108028
```

Since there are only 100k words in the book, for good measure, just x10 (`initDico()` is a helper to build the `List<Dico>` from the words):

```
List<Dico> dico = initDico(words);
List<Dico> bigDico = new ArrayList<>(10*dico.size());
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    bigDico.addAll(dico);
}
System.out.println(bigDico.size()); // 1080280
```

Build the weights map, using all words (`initWeights()` builds a frequency map of the words in the book):

```
Map<String, Double> weights = initWeights(words);
System.out.println(weights.size()); // 9449 distinct words
```

The the test of *merging* the 1M words against the map of weights:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
List<Dico> wDico = merge_list_map(bigDico, weights);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("===== Elapsed time (ms): "+(end-start)); 
// => 105 ms
```

The weights map is significantly smaller than yours, but it should not impact the the timing since the lookup operations are in quasi-constant
time.

This is no serious benchmark for the function, but it already shows that `merge_list_map()` should score less than 1s (loading and building list and map are not part of the function).

---

Just to complete the exercise, following are the initialisation methods used in the test above:

```
private static List<Dico> initDico(String[] terms) {
    List<Dico> dico = Arrays.stream(terms)
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .map(s -> new Dico(s, 1.0))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return dico;
}

// weight of a word is the frequency*1000
private static Map<String, Double> initWeights(String[] terms) {
    Map<String, Long> wfreq = termFreq(terms);
    long total = wfreq.values().stream().reduce(0L, Long::sum);
    return wfreq.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> (double)(1000.0*e.getValue()/total)));
}

private static Map<String, Long> termFreq(String[] terms) {
    Map<String, Long> wfreq = Arrays.stream(terms)
            .map(String::toLowerCase)
            .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));
    return wfreq;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method `contains()` for `list`. In this way you'll avoid the second `for`. Even if the `contains()` method has O(n) complexity, you should see a a small improvement. Of course, rememeber to re-implement the `equals()`. Otherwise you should use a second `Map`, as bot suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use the lookup functionality of the Map, as Adam pointed out, and use HashMap as implementation of Map - HashMap lookup complexity is O(1). This should result in increased performance.